# tensorboard weight histogram is not like normal distribution

Tags: python, neural-network, histogram, tensorboard

I can not understand why the weights are not like normal distribution.

[image]

actually I want to understand what is going on during weight changing and what is happening for gradients. but the problem is that weights in histogram are not looking like normal distribution.

bellow u can find the code:

```
iris_data_set = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
iris_data_set.head()
cols_to_norm = ['Sepal.Length' , 'Sepal.Width' , 'Petal.Length' , 
'Petal.Width']
iris_data_set[cols_to_norm] = iris_data_set[cols_to_norm].apply(lambda x:(x- 
 x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))
feat_data = iris_data_set.drop('Species', axis=1 )
label = iris_data_set['Species']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feat_data , label, 
test_size = 0.3 , random_state =101)

y_train = pd.get_dummies(y_train)
y_test = pd.get_dummies(y_test)

n_features = 4 
n_dense_neurons = 3
n_output = 3
training_steps =1000
#tf Graph input
X_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , shape= [None , n_features], 
name='Inputdata')
y_target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , shape= [None , n_output], 
name='Labeldata')
#Store layers

weights = {
'w1':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[n_features , n_dense_neurons]) , 
name = 'w1'), # Inputs -> Hidden Layer
'w2':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[n_dense_neurons , n_output]) , 
name = 'w2')
}

biases = {       
   'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[n_dense_neurons]) , 
name='b1'),   # First Bias
   'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[n_output]) , name='b2')
}

def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
   # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X_data , weights['w1']), biases['b1'])
   layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
   # Create a summary to visualize the first layer ReLU activation
   tf.summary.histogram("relu1", layer_1)

# Output layer
out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['w2']), biases['b2'])
return out_layer
with tf.name_scope('Model'):
   pred = multilayer_perceptron(X_data, weights, biases)
with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
   final_output = tf.nn.softmax(pred)
   deltas = tf.square (final_output - y_target)
   loss = tf.reduce_sum (deltas)
with tf.name_scope('SGD'):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    grads = tf.gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
    grads = list(zip(grads, tf.trainable_variables()))
    apply_grads = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=grads)
with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
     acc = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y_target, 1))
     acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(acc, tf.float32))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)

tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", acc)

for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    tf.summary.histogram(var.name, var)
for grad, var in grads:
    tf.summary.histogram(var.name + '/gradient', grad)
 # Merge all summaries into a single op
merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
with tf.Session() as sess: 
   sess.run(init)
   summary_writer= tf.summary.FileWriter("new6", 
   for i in range (training_steps):graph=tf.get_default_graph())
   _, c, summary = sess.run([apply_grads, loss, merged_summary_op],
                                feed_dict={X_data: X_train, y_target: 
   y_train})


if i % 20 == 0:
    summary_str = sess.run(merged_summary_op, feed_dict={X_data: 
   X_train, y_target: y_train})
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
    summary_writer.flush()
```

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem that they don't look normally distributed?

Comment: because the shape is not smooth. at least the first layer should look like a normal distribution. I can not interpret the histogram. in so many samples when they are training the data set, the weight matrix looks like a normal distribution. but here is not the case.

Comment: I mean even if we have a weight matrix of small size this should looks like normal distribution with peak in the middle and values decreasing in the sides.

Comment: No, that is an assumption and its wrong. Trained weights do not have to follow any specific distribution.

Comment: i have already written here, at least the first layer should look like a Gaussian distribution. the problem is that I can not understand the how we can interpret this histograms?